# How do I get the new screenshot tool available on Ubuntu 22.04 on older versions of ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, gnome, 22.04

I really like the new gnome 42 screenshot tool that comes with Ubuntu 22.04. In my opinion, it makes taking screenshots and doing screen recording so much easier. However, I reverted back to Ubuntu 20.04 because Ubuntu 22.04 wasn't good at memory management so at times my laptop felt slow even though I have tons of memory space.

Is there any way I can install the new gnome 42 screenshot on older versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: An almost classic [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): Real problem A (*at times my laptop felt slow*), preferred solution B (*reverted back to Ubuntu 20.04*), leading to super-hard and obscure technical question C (*install the new gnome 42 screenshot on older versions of Ubuntu*). We can certainly try to answer C (briefly: Super-difficult, experts only, many tears on the way), but you might get more useful advice if you asked about A instead.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, there may indeed a hard way - studying at the Gnome Shell javascript code in 22.04, then try incorporating and adapting that code in your own new extension, which you prepare to work in 20.04.

If you are not up to that task, and you do not find work of someone else who could have done this, then, practically speaking, no. The new screenshot tool is not an independent program anymore. It is integrated in Gnome Shell itself, pretty much like Gnome extensions also integrate themselves in the javascript part of Gnome Shell.